# No Keyboard Recognized after Startup

Tags: usb, keyboard, hardware

To preface, I am very new to Linux. I only know the basics of navigating the file structure, and checking IP addresses.  I am trying to get a Linux box stood up for my own personal fun, and also for my kid (8) who is getting to that point in school where he needs a computer more frequently, and I can start showing him some basic programming (he loves Scratch on the RaspberryPi).

I have an old PC tower that I am trying to install this onto. The Motherboard is an ASUS M2N-SLI deluxe, CPU = Athlon 64 X2 4200, RAM 3GB, Video GeForce 7600 GT. 500GB HD. This box just hit its 10th birthday, but has spent many years in a closet collecting dust.

Several years back I decided to put Debian on this box, version 7.8 according to the old ISO I have on a USB stick. I was able to successfully do so, but I never really used the box, and eventually it went back in the closet.  This weekend I decided to pull it out again. It fired right up and got all the way to the login prompt, where I discovered my keyboard didn't respond.

I restarted, and noticed the keyboard lights flashed (Caps/Num/Scroll), so I jumped into the BIOS, lo and behold, the keyboard is fine, I can navigate around just fine.  Restart -> login -> dead; now I am baffled. Restart again, and in the GRUB loader (no idea what this really is), there are 2 options for boot, regular and safe, So I hit the down arrow, and poof, it works. Finish loading the kernel in safe mode, and -- no keyboard.

This keyboard is a USB plug from Insignia (Best buy); I keep it around as my spare. It works fine for my RasPi, or an auxiliary for my laptop. I don't know about the mouse, I don't really have a chance to test it before the login screen, but I know it works in other machines.

I decided, "maybe this install just doesn't have the right drivers, I had a PS2 keyboard when I put debian on it". So I have burned a DVD of Mint 18.1, thrown it in the Drive, booted, and -- no keyboard. Same behavior.

I have seen some things about an IOMMU option in BIOS, or changing boot commands, but I don't have that setting in my motherboard, and I can't change a boot command for a DVD live load disc (Can I?)

I also have a USB to PS2 adapter, I can plug that in and still use the keyboard to jump around the BIOS or the GRUB screen, but the keyboard is still dead at login, for either Debian or MINT.

My alternative now is to upgrade/tech refresh my current PC Tower and hand it down. Or buy a $500 pre-canned box and install Minit (or other) from there. But the whole purpose of this endeavor was a cheap and quick means to get another computer up and running. It is turning out harder than expected.

Comment: If it works in safe mode, the problem shouldn't be too hard to track down. Please boot  in safe mode, and directly after boot, upload the output of `dmesg` somewhere, e.g. into a pastebin:  `dmesg > /tmp/safe.boot`, then upload `/tmp/safe.boot`. No screenshots, please. While you are in safe mode, make sure `sshd` is installed. Boot in normal mode, use a second computer to log in via `ssh` (`putty` in Windows), and do the same. Edit your question with the two links, and I'll have a look.

Comment: I have no keyboard in safe mode. I just have it at the BIOS and GRUB loader. I can select the standard boot or the SafeMode. I can also access a terminal like screen where i can enter GRUB commands, but i havent a clue what i am doing in there.

I would try the putty approach, but i dont know that a network is configured on it. For the Debian load, I hardwired a network cable from my router, and got into the routers config manager. I could see all the devices on the network, but the linux box wasnt on the list (could see my windows PC, phones, tablets etc)

Comment: Ah, I misread, sorry. It looks like the BIOS recognizes the keyboard, and then something goes wrong when Linux boots, but currently we can't see *what* goes wrong (and fix it). Do you see a graphical login screen, or does it stay on the text screen? What happens if you plug out your USB keyboard after it has finished booting, wait a bit, and then plug it in again? More ideas: Can you take out the harddisk, and read `/var/log/syslog` from a different computer? Can you boot with [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) from an USB stick or CD?

Comment: OK....updates:  I cant access the disk drive. I booted to the prior Debain, and got to the login prompt (dead), but plugged in the network cord again. This time it registed in my DHCP client. But Putty wouldnt connect to it. So, I pulled the HDD out of the tower, and placed in an external mount/case, but my PC cant read anything from it. Guessing this is a FAT/NTFS issue that windows fails at.  

For the Debain load, the default boot goes to the graphical login screen, Safe mode goes to a command line, niether allow keyboard inputs.

Comment: Since i had the HDD out of the tower, it seemed a good opportunity/test just to boot from the Mint DVD I made. Same behavior, keyboard works in BIOS, nothing after. it appears as though there is no power being sent to the USB. Turning the mouse over, there is no light from the optical port.

Comment: If you want to read the harddisk from Windows, you need [tools](https://www.howtoforge.com/access-linux-partitions-from-windows) to access the Linux ext2/ext3 filesystem. "No power to USB" would be decidedly odd. Next I'd try SystemRescueCD from an USB stick: The system is made to work on a wide range of hardware, and is a bit more careful during boot.

Comment: LIfe got in the way for the last few days. Hopefully i can get a SystemRescue cd/dvd built over the weekend. kids soccer and opening weekend of baseball might (will) get in the way.